# TD Ameritrade Phone App Giving Inconsistent Candle Charts

Tags: stock-analysis, chart, td-ameritrade

Just checking the stock BYND over 1 and 3 month periods I noticed that the same day was given a green or red candle depending on the length of the chart chosen. Am I missing something that is causing me to read the data wrong? This is likely. OR is there something wrong with the chart being produced by TDA? It’s my understanding that that candle is from 2/15/23 as shown in photo 3.

Has anyone else seen this scenario?

1 month view with stock showing a red loss for the day:

[image]

3 month view with same day showing a gain for the day:

[image]

zoomed in on the 3 month chart to show date:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With standard candlestick charts, hollow body means the stock opened lower and closed higher. A filled-in candle means the stock opened higher and closed lower.

The colors usually refer to the previous closing price. Red means that day's close was lower than the previous day's close. Green means the closing price was higher than the closing price the previous day.

Here, it appears that the discrepancy is only on the first day of the 1-month chart. Although BYND actually closed higher on that day than the prior day's close, it's possible that the chart coding might default to the first candle of every chart being red.

In any case, assuming the standard candlestick chart legend is being followed, the 3-month chart appears to be the correct one. Hollow - close>open, and green today's close>yesterday's close.

Comment: I think you're right about the first candle being defaulted red. I'd call that a bug and report it to TD.